# ERROR: subquery must return only one column

Tags: postgresql, subquery, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
INSERT 
INTO rooms(
    id,
    name,
    body,
    parents,
    tags,
    createtime,
    creator,
    deletetime,
    meta,
    params,
    terms,
    updater,
    updatetime,
    counts,
    identities) 
SELECT *
FROM dblink ('dbname=oldsb',
    'SELECT '
        '(SELECT newid FROM id_map WHERE oldid = entities.id) AS id, '
        'id AS name, '
        'description AS body, '
        'NULL AS parents, '
        'NULL AS tags, '
        'ROUND(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp)*1000) AS createtime, '
        'NULL AS creator, '
        'ROUND(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM deletetime)*1000) AS deletetime, '
        'json_build_object(''picture'', picture) AS meta, '
        'jsonb_object_agg(
            (SELECT * '
            'FROM jsonb_each(params) '
            'AS fields (name, value) '
            'WHERE name <> ''places'')) AS params, '
        'terms AS terms, '
        'NULL AS updater, '
        'EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM lAStseentime)*1000 AS updatetime, '
        'NULL AS counts, '
        'NULL AS identities '
    'FROM entities WHERE type=''room''') 
AS t(
    id uuid,
    name text,
    body text,
    parents uuid[],
    tags smallint[],
    createtime bigint,
    creator text,
    deletetime bigint,
    meta jsonb,
    params jsonb,
    terms tsvector,
    updater text,
    updatetime bigint,
    counts jsonb,
    identities text[]);
```

and I am getting the following error:

Executing Rooms migration query
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
CONTEXT:  Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute query.
table for updating identities in rooms.

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong with the query.

Comment: You need to replace the `SELECT *` inside the `jsonb_object_agg(` and select only a single column

Answer (score 0):

One of Yours subqueries returns multiple results. Probobly this one.

> SELECT newid FROM id_map WHERE oldid = entities.id

Add LIMIT 1 to the end and try again. In fact You can add LIMIT 1 to every subquery and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that jsonb_each(params) has more than one column?

```
jsonb_object_agg(
        (SELECT * '
        'FROM jsonb_each(params) '
        'AS fields (name, value) '
        'WHERE name <> ''places'')) AS params,
```

I don't know what jsonb_object_agg() does but I don't think it's designed to handle an input that is a table. Usually, aggregate functions combine one or more **rows** of results into a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Check [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) documentation for json_each function. json_each AND jsonb_each work the same way.